# Importing modules between sibling sub-packages in python(intra-package referenences)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I was reading through the Python module documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages  and was trying understand intra-package references: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references using the `sound` example creating the same directory structure and leaving all files blank initially. According to the linked documentation:

> When packages are structured into subpackages (as with the sound package in the example), you can use absolute imports to refer to submodules of siblings packages. For example, if the module sound.filters.vocoder needs to use the echo module in the `sound.effects` package, it can use `from sound.effects import echo`.

However, when I try this on my local machine, as with setting the contents of `sound/filters/vocoder.py` to:

`from sound.effects import echo`

Running it as with:

`$python vocoder.py`

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vocoder.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sound.effects import echo
ImportError: No module named sound.effects
```

If I go into the `sound` directory and try the following in an iPython shell and try to import the package as with:

```
In [2]: import filters.vocoder
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0217a888946e> in <module>()
----> 1 import filters.vocoder

/home/rootavish/sound/filters/vocoder.py in <module>()
----> 1 from sound.effects import echo

ImportError: No module named sound.effects
```

or

```
In [3]: import sound.filters.vocoder
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-09d9adcc27d8> in <module>()
----> 1 import sound.filters.vocoder

ImportError: No module named sound.filters.vocoder
```

I still have problems.

So what am I missing here? I thought absolute imports was the way to go when working with sub-packages.

Comment: You may have already checked, but do you have an `__init__.py` file in the package directory?

Comment: @EvanWise yes, I double-checked whether I have the right directory structure or not, it's the same as the tree given on there.